# How to pass parameter value for rule condition in DRL file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools

I am new in Drools. I want to pass parameter for rule condition in rule.drl file.

Currently i have code like this :-

```
rule "PREPAID TOP UP LIMIT" salience 1

when
cardObject : Card(cardType=="prepaid" && loadCash > 25000);
then
cardObject.setTransactionResposne(false);
cardObject.setMessage("Top up limit exceeds ");
end;
```

As you can see in this code cardType and loadCash is compare with "prepaid" and 25000 respectively with static value. But i want initiate this static value from java classes.

So, How can i pass this parameter. Please share some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Pass the conditions into working memory.
2. Declare the conditions as global variables.

Global variables are generally frowned upon, but I will include this for completeness.

---

For the first option, passing the conditions into working memory, I would suggest creating a simply object which has these conditions declared along with appropriate getters/setters.

For example:

```java
public class CardLimits {
  private String type;
  private Integer limit;
  // getters and setters here
}
```

You would pass the `CardLimits` instance (or instances if you have multiple types) into working memory alongside your `Card` instance. Then your rule could be as follows:

```
rule "PREPAID TOP UP LIMIT" 
salience 1
when
  CardLimits( $max: limit != null, $type: type == "prepaid" )
  cardObject : Card( cardType == $type && loadCash > $max);
then
  cardObject.setTransactionResposne(false);
  cardObject.setMessage("Top up limit exceeds ");
end
```

(Minor nitpick: the semi-colon you have after `end` shouldn't be there. Also you've spelled 'response' wrong on the right hand side.)

The CardLimits instance would be passed into the rules alongside your Card instance like this:

```java
KieSession kieSession = ...; 

Card card = ...; // the Card you are passing into the rules
CardLimits limits = ...; // the limits

kieSession.insert( card ); 
kieSession.insert( limits ); 
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

Note that for this structure, you can have a single rule for multiple types of limits.

So, for example, let's say you had two types of cards "prepaid" and "gift", with different CardLimits instances describing their limits. You could then have a single rule to handle both like this:

```
rule "ANY TOP UP LIMIT" 
salience 1
when
  CardLimits( $max: limit != null, $type: type ) // no restriction on 'type'
  cardObject : Card( cardType == $type && loadCash > $max); 
then
  cardObject.setTransactionResposne(false);
  cardObject.setMessage("Top up limit exceeds ");
end
```

I would also suggest using an enum instead of a String for the card type.

By passing in an object, you also have the freedom to add additional conditions in the future. For example, let's say you want to refuse top-ups if the card expires within a certain number of days -- you can add that to your conditions object as needed.

---

For completeness's sake, your alternative is to use globals. This is generally something you want to avoid, for the same reasons we try to avoid global variables in most languages unless there is no other choice. This was a pretty common practice when I first started doing Drools (back in Drools 5) but has since generally fallen out of favor.

```
global Integer max;
global String type;

rule "PREPAID TOP UP LIMIT" 
salience 1
when
  cardObject : Card( cardType == type && loadCash > max);
then
  cardObject.setTransactionResposne(false);
  cardObject.setMessage("Top up limit exceeds ");
end
```

This will limit you to only a single type and max value for all rules. So you can't process multiple cards at the same time.

You set globals when you call the rules:

```java
KieSession kieSession = ...; 

Card card = ...; // the Card you are passing into the rules

// set the globals
kieSession.setGlobal( "max", (Integer)25000 );
kieSession.setGlobal( "type", "prepaid" );

kieSession.insert( card ); 
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

I would not recommend using Globals for this. I only include this possibility because it is something you *could* do.

Answer (score 0):

To pass parameters to your rule.drl file , first you must be clear what to do to initialize Drools session in your code . In very basic form it can be done as

`KieSession kieSession=new DroolsBeanFactory().getKieSession();` .

After initializing the session, i see you are evaluating `cardType` & `loadCash` for Card object . These two values are basically part of a Card object constructor that takes in two values , namely "cardType" & "loadCash" . So first ensure you have such bean or POJO created already in your code , or else create it . After that what you need to do is to pass this "Card" object as a whole to the rule.drl file . It can be done in following manner to start with :

```
class Card
{

private String cardType;
private int loadCash;

Card(String cardType,int loadCash)
{
this.cardType = cardType;
this.loadCash = loadCash;
}

public String getCardType()
{
return cardType;
}
public int getLoadCash()
{
return loadCash;
}

// Other methods as per your business-logic
}

public void setCardValue(Card card){    
        kieSession.insert(card);
        kieSession.fireAllRules();  // this will now execute all the rules in your drl file.

    }
```

You can always look upto the KieSession documentation here and check what if allows for you to accomplish .
https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.Beta2/javadocs/org/kie/api/runtime/KieSession.html
Please up-vote the answer if this helps you .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have integrated this session in my code and also there is POJO class to set Card but i want to pass "prepaid" and 25000 in dynamic manner. For example, one bank has limit is 25000 and second bank has 30000. So how can I replace this parameter value dynamic according bank type from java side to drl file.

Comment: Why are you linking to documentation for the beta version of a 7-year-old release??